# One/more network adapter(s) are not vmxnet3

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation 14. I import Palo Alto Firewall from ova file and try to do some labs. But this error is show up : 
[image]

Please show me how to fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to fix it. Go to your vm location and edit file .vmx with notepad. Replace **ethernet3.virtualDev = "e1000"**  with  **ethernet3.virtualDev = "vmxnet3"**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but a good thought would be to shutdown the VM and attempt the following: 
To configure virtual network adapter settings for a selected virtual machine, select VM > Settings, click the Hardware tab, select the virtual network adapter.

Pulled from the following link: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-C82DCB68-2EFA-460A-A765-37225883337D.html